# Empty string for system property for wifi.interface on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and Tab 2

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am trying to find the name of the Wifi interface through a call to android.os.SystemProperties.get("wifi.interface").

On most devices I have used, it seems to work fine, but on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (Samsung GT-P5100) and Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (Samsung GT-P7100), I am getting an empty string in response. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong here, or how I can get the Wifi interface name more reliably? I have seen the option to go through all network interfaces, get their IP addresses and get the IP address of the device and match the two. Will try it, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Get the IP address of the WiFi:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)        
context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
```

And then match it to the same IP from NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()

Answer (score 0):

I think "wifi.interface" property is not set in JB of note 2.

This is set in other devices variants like S2 etc.,

This need to be set to "wlan0" in one of the device specific rc file.